# Oracle Forms - two identical blocks but only first block shows data

Tags: oracleforms

Two blocks based on different tables with same structure. Control field determines which table shows data. Data exists in both tables. Problem is data is only displayed from table that is block 1. Block 2 never shows data. What is the trick to allow data to be seen in block 2. Both blocks sit on same canvas. Thanks.

Comment: how are the blocks builts? Tried `go_block('block_name');` & follow it up with `execute_query;`?

Answer (score 0):

Create the relationship between this two blocks and data will be automatically retrived based on this relation..

P.S: I hope there will be some relation between this two table..

Answer (score 0):

simply add the following code to the when-new-form-instance:

`go_block('block_one');

execute_query;

go_block('block_two');

execute_query;`

I hope it works for you